# How to move magento 2 swatches on category page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm attempting to move the swatches of each product on the category page directly under the product images versus under the price box. So far not having much luck. I have tried altering  *selectorProduct* within `Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml` as well as changing settings inside swatch-renderer.js to get them to load where i choose. No luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you're after is **vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml**, specifically line 74

```
<?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>
```

That's the line that calls the swatches renderer and places the swatches on the page for each item.  So just copy list.phtml into **app/design/frontend/YOURVENDOR/YOURTHEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/** and then move that line of code up to just under

```
<div class="product details product-item-details">
```

and you're good to go.